# Android - Switch track not drawn when turned off

Tags: android

I am using `android.widget.Switch` in a part of my app. The problem is that the track is not drawn when its turned off.

I did a little bit of debugging and found that the track is in fact there but, is just a translucent white, and hence will not show up against my white background.

Please see the picture below. First is when its ON, Second is when its OFF, and Third is OFF which black background on parent.

What I am wondering is; is using 'Switch' really this tricky? or am I missing something? I prefer not to use any custom drawable for track or the thumb.

UPDATE:
I see that this is happening since I am using `android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar` as my theme. If I use `android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Light`, there is no such issue. But unfortunately I need to stick with first theme.
Can anybody tell me how can I customize `android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar` so that I can probably solve this issue?

[image: First is when its ON, Second is when its OFF, and Third is OFF with black background on parent.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After another round of research I am able to finally do it.
Posting here for my own and possibly others' reference.

It turns out that theme in fact can be customized at view level using the `android:theme` property.

So, in my case, all that I had to do was to add `android:theme="@style/AppThemeSettings"` to the Switch in the xml. `AppThemeSettings` is extending from `android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Light` and everything is good now.